# CSS Float Question (Strange behaviors found)

Tags: javascript, html, css, class

Dears,

Below is my simple float program and I also attach a picture of the result.  My question is: When the width in class "two" is 300px, the div 2 is moved next to the floated div 1, this is also my expectation.  However, when i changed the width in class "two" from 300px to 200px, div 2 is kept under div 1, and div 3 is moved to overlap with div 2 (see the attached picture) Why? [image]

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.one{
    background: yellow;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center; 
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000;
    Float: left;
    }

.two {
    background: rgb(55, 0, 255);
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center; 
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000;  
  }

.three {
    background: rgb(255, 0, 76);
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center; 
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000;
   }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class = "one">1</div>
    <div class = "two">2</div>
    <div class = "three">3</div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thanks. And i had go to your jsfiddle and check, i also don't understand why.  But div 2 is also overlapped with div 1 in the jsfiddle.  I use vscode editor and the chrome browser to doing this...

Comment: Ok couldn't reproduce it because there is an intrusive backtick next to your opening html tag.

Comment: @Teemu their question is why it behaves how it behaves not how it should supposed to look in the end though.

Comment: @Teemu sorry but that's not an answer.

Comment: @pso Isn't asking "why" about the behavior of a single native feature very basics? You rareley get your job done by asking "why", instead asking "how" would push you forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I think I figured it out. The problem lies in the fact that it just looks like as if the second `div` is below the first. It actually properly overlaps the first `div` and just leaves the text behind. You can see this if you add opacity or remove the `background-color` of the first div.

You can add `display: flow-root` to your second (and third) div to fix this if needed or use 'float: left' on all of them as suggested.

```html
<html>
<head>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class = "one">1</div>
    <div class = "two">22222222</div>
    <div class = "three">3</div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

```css
.one{
    background: transparent;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000;
    float: left;
    }

.two {
    background: rgb(55, 0, 255);
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000;
 }

.three {
    background: rgb(255, 0, 76);
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Pso.  You just inspired me that the element followed the floated element, their properties will automatically shift to the space of the floated element except the text element. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you add this style to your blue box;

```css
.two {
  border: 10px solid #0ff;
}
```

You can see blue box is already under the yellow box.
The only thing that is absurd here is; blue box text alignment centered only on the rendered area of the blue box.